# How to remove hard links on ubuntu without losing original file?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, find

I am on ubuntu and I use `dropbox`. The problem is that I have some problems of synchronization because I have many hard links in my picture folder.

How can I remove all of them with a simple command WITHOUT losing any pictures? For a single file I have found the flowing command

```
find /home -xdev -samefile "filename" | xargs rm
```

But I don't know how to do it for all files?

thx in advance

Informations about my filesystem:

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  7,7G     0  7,7G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1,6G  2,4M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3 ext4      435G  203G  211G  50% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     7,7G  756M  7,0G  10% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/571981/edit) your post to include information on which filesystem you are using?

Comment: That command would also erase the "reference" file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove *"extra"* copies of all files like this:

```
find /home -xdev -type f -links +1 -delete
```

but should be aware that some of those extra copies may be hard-linked to places outside **`/home`** (and may appear to be missing).

The **`-links +1`** tells `find` to select only the files (`-type f`) which have more than one hard-link.

You could (with more work) use `find` to print the inode value for each file and sort the result and (with `awk`) write a list of files to remove via `xargs`, but doing that would run into problems with filenames with special characters (including blanks).  But that would be how to eliminate surprise when a file is linked outside **`/home`**.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove a file as long as there are more than one hard link to it, the data will be removed when the last hard link is removed. The number of links can be retrieved with `stat -c '%h' {file}` (*), so you can erase all files with more than one hardlink on them, something like this:

```
for file in *
do
   links=$(stat -c '%h' "$file")
   [[ -f "$file" ]] && [[ $links -gt 1 ]] && rm "$file" 
done
```

As they says, *in the end, there will be only one*, and the survivor will be the last one checked, depending on directory processing order, alphabetical order, etc...

(*) It also appears in the output of `ls -l`, but this is harder to parse...

Comment: Thank you! so I must write this script and tun it in the desired folder. I am sorry to ask but I want to be sure that the hard links will be remove only in my ```/home/paul/pictures``` and then I will move it to dropbox

Answer (score 2):

In Unix/Linux/MacOS a file name in a directory references an inode (indirect node), that is the structure on disk that *really* is the file. This association  of a name with an inode is called a *hard link* as opposed to a *soft link* that is essentially just a file containing the name under which the file can be found. Soft links can break if some part of the path to the file linked to is renamed or removed, whereas renaming/moving one hard link doesn't affect the others at all.

Thus, there is no "original file", *all* hard links have exactly the same status. The inode records how many hard links refer to the file (`ls -l` shows this number as the second field; it is usually 1 for files --one link only-- and 2 for directories --the link in the parent and '.' in the directory itself; if there are subdirectories, each one refers to it's parent via '..' and thus the count grows).  The space used by the file is reclaimed when the link count reaches 0.